# Could not find CSS class selector message on content pages

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have two CSS files style1.css and style2.css. Each of them include many lines of styles.

I use them in all project pages. I have no problem with using them on Master page but, the content pages(the pages that inherited from master page) can't find the second CSS file!

For example on a inherited page when a div's class is set to a style from style2.css, it doesn't work. It can't find the CSS selector. :(

Master page's head tag:

```
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection,print" href="~/css/style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection,print" href="~/css/style2.css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Also, I've linked the CSS file on the inherited page but doesn't work.
Even, on the designing state the visual studio can't go to definition of the CSS selector line by pressing the F12 key on the desired selector name, so it raises "Could not find CSS class selector 'loginform'" error.

Answer (score 0):

Do it declaratively in the master page by dragging the CSS files from Solution Explorer window to the code view of the mark-up.

Comment: Lose the "~" in the href attributes - these are not server controls.